# the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory with iis hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

NET MVC web app with WEBAPI and .NET 4.5
I host it on local IIS Server and it work properly in my matchain.

I host it on other 3 machine all have same configuration as WINDOWS-7
it work only on one machine and the others give error like bellow:

> "the web server is configured to not list the contents of this
>   directory."

I followed the steps below:

1. Control panel -> Program and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or of -> 
   check all boxes of IIS and IIS Hostable Web Core
2. Install -> .NetFramework V4.5.1
3. Restart
4. in CMD as Admisistrator -> for 32bit & 64bit OS

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
>   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

5. Open IIS -> ISAPI and CGI Restrictions -> ASP.NET v4.0.30319 -> Allow
6. Sites -> Add Web Site

> ```
>  a. Site Name :- API
>  b. application pool :- ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
>  c. Path :- D:\API
>  d. Port :- 8081 -> OK
> ```

Comment: Please then clarify that your problem is not the listing of the directory, but you can not run the MVC

Comment: it give me the directory error. so i ask you that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to run a hello world asp.net mvc application on the 3 machines to make sure mvc is working first. I also like to set my app pools to integrated mode and not classic. There must be configuration difference between the machine where it worked and the other 2 machines. Look into app pool settings values and into the machine web.config and do diff merge and you should notice the issue.

Comment: it was Windows 7 issue.
it require Win 7 Service Pack 1 to do this task.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable directory browser in IIS solve my problem. Please see this screen shot

[image: iis directory browsing screen shot]

Comment: i don't want to enable directory i just want to run my mvc app on iis. if i enable it it will not run my mvc app as i needed.. plsease give any other suggestion.

Comment: Directory browsing is quite useless for mvc apps as there are normally no *.html or other files to browse. Pages are dynamically compiled and rendered for each request.